# DLL link wrong in Unity3D

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine

currently I am working on a projet to create a plugin for Unity3D based on OpenCV. There is no problem for me to integrate it inside unity editor ,but if I output unity3D application by building. I meet one strange problems. I put all dll inside assets->plugins folder. When i build application, I can find all this dll inside the appnames_data->plugins folder, but the application will not work unless i copy all the opencv dll files to the application root directory (in the same folder as the applicaiton.exe). It's not beautiful for an application. How can i ask the application to search opencv dll inside plugins folder?